# Ionic 1 ios http get not working

Tags: ios, cordova, http, ionic-framework

I'm developing an application for IOS with Ionic v1. I have added cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin to my application. It doesn't allow me to use http calls only in IOS device. It's working fine in Android and Ionic Serve. Actually, it was working fine but I don't know why it stopped working. I removed and reinstalled all plugins and IOS builds. Here is my config.xml file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> <widget id="com.xxx.xxx" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>xxx</name>
<author email="xxx" href="xxx">
  xxx
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="2000" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />
<platform name="ios">
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120"/>
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100"/>
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120"/>
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180"/>
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144"/>
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152"/>
    <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167"/>
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58"/>
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87"/>
    <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
    <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
</platform>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^2.4.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^1.7.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~1.3.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-media-with-compression" spec="~2.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="~1.6.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
<plugin name="es6-promise-plugin" spec="~4.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="~1.3.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-image-picker" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.7" /></widget>
```

Also here is my package.json

```
{
   "name": "",
   "version": "1.1.1",
   "description": "xxx",
   "dependencies": {
   "async": "^1.4.0",
   "gulp": "^3.5.6",
   "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^1.5.0",
   "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
   "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
   "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
   "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
   "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2",
   "require-dir": "^0.3.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
   "bower": "^1.3.3",
   "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
   "shelljs": "^0.3.0",
   "del": "^1.2.0",
   "gulp-flatten": "^0.1.1",
   "gulp-if": "^1.2.5",
   "gulp-json-editor": "^2.2.1",
   "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.0",
   "gulp-ng-annotate": "^1.1.0",
   "gulp-ng-constant": "^0.3.0",
   "gulp-preprocess": "^1.2.0",
   "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
   "gulp-shell": "^0.4.2",
   "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
   "gulp-useref": "^1.2.0",
   "gulp-zip": "^3.0.2",
   "jshint": "^2.8.0",
   "minimist": "^1.1.2",
   "mv": "^2.1.1"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
   "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
   "cordova-plugin-console",
   "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
   "cordova-plugin-device",
   "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
   "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
   "cordova-plugin-image-picker",
   "cordova-plugin-transport-security"
],
"cordovaPlatforms": [],
"cordova": {
"plugins": {
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
    "cordova-plugin-compat": {},
    "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
    "cordova-media-with-compression": {}
},
"platforms": []
 }
}
```

Also here is my Content-security-policy tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * 'self' https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net data:; default-src * gap://ready file:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; object-src 'self' blob:; media-src 'self' blob:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a conflict between "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" and "cordova-plugin-file" plugins and when I fix the version conflicts, it started working again.